# Is storing filename in varchar datatype column good?

Tags: mysql, sql-optimization

Is storing filename in `varchar` **datatype** column good? Is there other way on handling files for your software like creating a folder by numeric Id and just checking if a file exists in the folder in your application logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Filenames are strings and should be stored as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the file name should be varchar.

Having a **numeric id** is a good practice generally for performance in mysql. For instance, **int** max size is **4** bytes. But **varchar** max size goes upto **9-12** bytes. Varchar also uses different characters sets like utf etc which is why (some other reasons) it takes more space.

> If the varchar will be 20 characters, and the int is 4, then if you
>   use an int, your index will have FIVE times as many nodes per page of
>   index space on disk... Which means that traversing the index will
>   require one fifth as many physical and/or logical reads.

It kind of both depends on your **length of numeric id** and **filename char length**. And also, having a numeric id might complicate the situation a bit for you. Because even minor changes in numeric values might change file names, or change in filenames might also change numeric values.

And also, remember you should write a script or do something when ever you enter a new file name. Something has to convert the file name to numeric id. If the filenames remains same always, may be a numeric id is a good option.

> Finally, I would say it all depends on your application, size of table
>   (no of rows), length of file name, length of numeric id etc.